# How to add pause when adding item to adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I`m new here. Here is my question. I have an array list and adapter (RecyclerView). I want to make pause after inserting one item after another. If I add one item, animation goes fine. And even when I send multiple items to adapter it is not look terrible, but to the usability concerns, I want to add them one by one with pause. What I did. If I do this code in my fragment, no pause at all. Items appear in one moment.

```
    for( int i = 0; i<filteredList.size();i++){

        try {
            mAdapter.add(filteredList.get(i));
            Thread.sleep(350);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If I add similar code to adapter, it stacks delay and then all items appear same way. May be I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that handlder is the solution.

### int dlay;

Handler handler = new Handler();

```
    for( int i = 0; i<filteredList.size();i++){

        final int finalI = i;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.add(filteredList.get(finalI));
            }
        }, dlay);


        dlay = dlay + 350;
```